# Tomcat load balancer creating new sessions only when using SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, load-balancing, redhat

I have a web app hosted on two Tomcat servers, identical WARs and server.xml.
I don't have access to change any of the Apache settings - as such, I know that load balancing works as we have tested by shutting down one server and not the other, etc. Based on Tomcat logs I see both being used.

When using the default Tomcat HTTP port 8080 (in my case that was changed to 8083, nonissue) sessions are retained fine.

However, I made a change to use SSL, port 443 and now sessions are invalidated anywhere from 30 seconds - 5 minutes after creation. I assume this has something to do with session replication as I have not made any changes to the server.xml or web.xml besides pointing to the keystore :

```
  <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" scheme="https" sslProtocol="TLS"
           maxThreads="150" 
           clientAuth="false"  keystoreFile="ssl/keystore.jks" keystorePass="123" />
```

I'm not exactly sure what else to copy here as the only change to the server.xml has literally be these few lines - I assume the added security is for some reason invalidating the session.

I currently have a test server serving the application on HTTP and HTTPS - even accessing the app at the same time, HTTP goes through fine and retains the session, HTTPS refuses to hold on to the session for longer than 5 minutes.

For what it's worth the SSL cert is installed to both Tomcat servers rather than at the load balancer - according to https://serverfault.com/questions/248139/apache-ssl-losing-session-over-load-balancer that may be the issue? I've only coded the application and changed some of the xml configurations - not sure if this is necessarily an issue I can fix.

Comment: Have you tried sticky sessions? Do you use jvmRoute in your tomcat engine configuration?

Comment: I haven't - but thanks for the direction :). I'll update my question appropriately based on how it goes!

Comment: Adding the jvmroute will add a postfix to your jsessionid. You can improve the call monitoring doing so. Your mentioned link contains a nice solution using Apache HTTPd.